# How to take multiple data in one checkbox value in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, checkbox

Here I just grabbed the ID or a data in the check box. But I want to capture more data with the ID. How to do it?
I don't know any language better than PHP.
`How to take multiple data in checkbox value PHP.<input type="checkbox" name="check_data[]"  value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">`

Comment: what are the data you want along with it? please mention your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what data you want to insert. For example if you want to insert id, username and birthday in value:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check_data"  value="id, username, birthday"/>
```

after you submit your form, you can catch the values from that checkbox like below:

```
$checkboxValues = explode(" ", $_POST['check_data']);
```

Comment: And how do I catch it?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ']' in....
Ero is coming.

Comment: i have editted my answer. Please check it

Comment: A row can contain multiple data. Let's say
ID ROW contains three such as 12,14,16. In this case $id shows the latest data "16" when it is echoed out.